# Laravel Sanctum API Authentication: Token expired error after moving to new VPS

Tags: php, laravel, vps

I have a Laravel application using Sanctum for API authentication. Everything was working fine on my old server; I could generate tokens and authenticate API requests without any issue. However, after moving the source code to a new VPS, I started facing a problem.

The route to create a new token is still working fine, and I'm able to generate new tokens. However, when I try to use these tokens for authenticating requests, I'm encountering a 'token expired' error.

I've already performed database migrations (including the personal_access_tokens table) on the new VPS, but the issue persists. The environment on the new VPS is almost identical to the old one, and no significant changes were made to the source code during the transition.

Below is the code I'm using to generate tokens:

`$success['token'] = $user->createToken('jwt')->plainTextToken;`

What could be causing the tokens to expire immediately after generation on the new VPS? Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or does anyone have suggestions for what to try next to resolve this?

Comment: check with timezone settings in your applications

Comment: @Shyam it is showing Kolkata